# Timer start at 3am every day

Tags: c#

I found this code. But i would like to know if is possible that instead of intervat program will start every day at 3 am?

edit: code
http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=483012

thx

Comment: What code would that be?

Comment: Explicitly mark your code as such in the editor before submitting your question.

Comment: sorry code isn't visible, now is ok. This is code: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=483012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that if you are not using the **task scheduler** your service will have to run continuously. You need to change the example you link to as follows:

1. The example code you link to uses an interval of 2 seconds. You may shorten the length of the interval to 1 second or even less.
2. The implementation of the OnTick(...) method should check if it's 3AM. If this is the case, do whatever it is you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using Task Scheduler, no need for controlling this programmatically. Unless its a windows service you are implementing, in that case you would need to check the time on the hour and do your processing respectively (and that's not taking into account if your using different timezones)